# ng-click is not working in $window.open

Tags: angularjs

I am generating  tag with ng-click option , but ng-click is not calling the corresponding function. Below is the code...

**1) Javascript**

```
var buffer ='';
buffer += "<div id='Content' x-ng-controller='HomePageMainCntrl'>";
                     buffer += "<table>";
                     for(i=0;i<data.newsArchiveList.length;i++)
                     {
                        //alert(data.newsArchiveList[i].title);
                         buffer += "<tr>";
                         buffer += "<td align=left >"+data.newsArchiveList[i].createDate+"</td>";
                         buffer += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
                         buffer += "<td align=left><a href='' ng-click=showNewsItem(4100); title='Click for more detail'>"+data.newsArchiveList[i].title+"</a>";
                         buffer += "</td>";
                         buffer += "</tr>";
                     }
                     buffer += "</table>";
                     buffer += "</div>"
```

*Buffer out put is :::

```
<div class='p3rMiddleBodyCommon' id='Content' x-ng-controller='HomePageMainCntrl'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align=left>2015-07-31</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align=left><a href='' ng-click=showNewsItem(4100); title='Click for more detail'>Testing_Cma_Admin</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align=left>2015-04-17</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align=left><a href='' ng-click=showNewsItem(4100); title='Click for more detail'>PLEASE READ - TEST</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

*

```
                     var myWindow1 = $window.open("", "News Archive", 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=650, height=550,left = 300,top=100');
                     myWindow1.document.write(buffer);


$scope.showNewsItem  = function(id)
    {
        alert('showNews Item called '+id);
}
```

New window is opened,  but ng-click function is not getting called. 
Please help  me

Comment: you have to add function in quotes like `ng-click='showNewsItem(4100)'`

Comment: can you create plunker so its easy to find issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect. You need to replace this `ng-click=showNewsItem(4100);` by this `ng-click="showNewsItem(4100)"`.

`ng-click` always need `"` like all angularJS attribute

**Edit :**

You have some `;` that shouldn't be there in the middle of your anchor.. I think I have fix all the mistake here.

```
var buffer ='';
buffer += "<div id='Content' x-ng-controller='HomePageMainCntrl'>";
                     buffer += "<table>";
                     for(i=0;i<data.newsArchiveList.length;i++)
                     {
                        //alert(data.newsArchiveList[i].title);
                         buffer += "<tr>";
                         buffer += "<td align='left' >"+data.newsArchiveList[i].createDate+"</td>";
                         buffer += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
                         buffer += "<td align='left'><a href='' ng-click='showNewsItem(4100)' title='Click for more detail'>"+data.newsArchiveList[i].title+"</a>";
                         buffer += "</td>";
                         buffer += "</tr>";
                     }
                     buffer += "</table>";
                     buffer += "</div>"
```

Comment: Move the " after the click in this - ng-"click

Comment: @OriDrori Thx for this

Comment: <div class="p3rMiddleBodyCommon" id="Content" x-ng-controller="HomePageMainCntrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align=left>2015-07-31</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align=left><a href='' ng-click="showNewsItem(4100)" ; title='Click for more detail'>Testing_Cma_Admin</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>    still it is not working !

Comment: @user1656315 You keep adding syntax error man. Your remore a quote from `href`. It will add the all syntax in edit.

Comment: removed quote from href .  <td align=left><a href ng-click="showNewsItem(4100)"; title="Click for more detail">Testing_Cma</a></td>

Comment: @user1656315 Check my edit. Moreover, why you have a `href` attribute ?

Comment: href is for link, when I click "Testing_Cma_Admin", it should open another window through that function call

Comment: href is there,  and ng-click is there. I am getting a link. But when i click that link, it should invoke the function through ng-click. But it is not happening..

Comment: x-ng-controller is not a mistake. It's a correct usage. 
E.g. `data-ng-controller`, `x-ng-controller` and `ng-controller` can be used. You can see in the documentation that in the normalizing process of a directive they will actively strip 'x' or 'data' from the front of the element/attribute. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @cverb Ok thanks. I didn't know this syntax. I just touhgh it was one more typo.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
buffer += '<td align=left><a href="" ng-click="showNewsItem(4100)"; title="Click for more detail">'+data.newsArchiveList[i].title+'</a>';
                     buffer += '</td>';
```

Comment: No,   it s not working ...   <div class="p3rMiddleBodyCommon" id="Content" x-ng-controller="HomePageMainCntrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align=left>2015-07-31</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align=left><a href='' ng-click="showNewsItem(4100)" ; title='Click for more detail'>Testing_Cma_Admin</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

Comment: Why are you giving a href? Use somthing like a <span> or <div>

Comment: href is for link, when I click  "Testing_Cma_Admin", it should open another window.

Comment: What do you really wish to do? Open a new window or run a function?

Comment: we sud call a function only. that function call is opening a new window. First of all we should invoke a function. but function is not getting called...

Comment: so instead of using <a href> you just make the function call. And in that function, locate to some other url.